# Gallery preview with flexbox

Tags: css, layout, sass, flexbox

I aim to style a list as this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evrk2.jpg).

Basically I have an `ul` of four `li` elements containing an image.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>
            <img />
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

The images inside the boxes should be responsive and centered in the blue boxes independently of their sizes.

At the moment, the best solution I made is this:

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:0;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    &>*{
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        &:first-child{
            border:1px solid blue;
            width:68%;
            height:100%;
            margin-right:2%;
        }
        &:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+4){
            flex:1 0 auto;
            width:30%;
            border:1px solid green;
            height:30%;
        }
        &:nth-child(3){
            margin:1% 0;
        }
    }
    img{
        max-width:80%;
        width:auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid any misunderstandings, post a _working_ code snippet showing what does not work, image included.